# Is it necessary to removeEventListener before each addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom

I bind `click` event to a button duplicated, like this:

```
var dom_btn = doc.getElementById('btn');

dom_btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

//Is it necessary to removeEventListener before each addEventListener?
//dom_btn.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

dom_btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
dom_btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Your question is missing the most important part: the question itself.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: _"I bind click event to a button duplicated, like this:"_ , _"Is it necessary to removeEventListener before each addEventListener?"_ Is expected result for cloned element to have event listeners removed?

Comment: That's actually a good question. I'm kinda curious to know the answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sorry for that. I approve the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was unclear, the question was:

> Is it necessary to removeEventListener before each addEventListener?

No.

But it *will* save a tiny bit of browser performance (the `eventListener`s will pile on top of each other, but only one will fire after each click.)

Here's a proof (and a sandbox you can mess around in):

https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/zwrxc1dy/